# A Challenging Problem in Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want to prove or disprove by giving a counterexample: There is no entire function $f$ such that $f(R)\subset R$ and $f(i)=f(-i)=2019i$.

I appreciate any help in this problem as I have no clue about this problem.

Comment: If $f\left(\mathcal{R}\right)\subset \mathcal{R}$, then $f^*(z) =f(z^*)$, therefore $f(i)=f(-i)^*$.

Comment: @DonThousand : That function isn’t entire

Comment: @CountIblis What does * means?

Comment: @CountIblis does it mean conjugate?

Comment: Yes, the complex conjugate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just adding some details to the comment by Count Iblis: for any entire fucntion $f$ the function $g$ defined by $g(z)=\overset {-} {f(\overset {-} {z})}$ is also an entire function (as seen from power series expansion). In this case $f=g$ or $f-g=0$ on $\mathbb R$. Since $\mathbb R$ has limit points in $\mathbb C$ it follows that $f-g=0$ everywhere. Now put $z=i$ in this to get a  contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer in which you used the identity theorem. Putting $z=i$ we do not get $f(i)=g(i)$ because $g(i)=-2019i$? Now, I wonder how $2019i$ plays to get contradiction.

Comment: $f(i)=g(i)$ says $2019i=-2019i$ which is a contradiction.